# Error in creating build with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, executable-jar

I have java program ini maven and I would like to make an build for the same.
I have seen this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMHhLsMC1NI

But I am having error in maven-assemblu-plugin.
Check out this image.
[image]

My Pom File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>Listener</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>
                maven-assembly-plugin
            </artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Executor</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (on windows)

Go to artifacts and create a new artifact jar.

Then go to Build and click on 'Build Artifact'.